# How to remove dual boot with Debian GNU/Linux and Windows 10 (Beginner and unexpected result)

Tags: system-installation, dual-boot, uninstall

I need assistance with how to remove Debian GNU/Linux from my Windows 10 PC which was an unexpected result from an install for a course.  I have this installed on 2 PCs but only need to remove this on one for now as I am still taking courses.

I don't know if this is the forum for this so please guide me to a another resource if you cannot assist.  I am very much a beginner with very limited knowledge with Linux and I am not certain if this is a Linux question or a Windows question because I am not certain if this can be removed another way via linux and/or windows.

As part of a set of online courses I have been taking I had to install VMware Workstation Player and Kali Linux some months ago.  To be honest I can't recall which of these installs caused what appears to be a dual boot.  This result for a dual boot was not communicated as part of the install for the course (with limited instructions).  Nevertheless this did not cause any issues with my Windows PC.  I would just boot into Windows, launch my VM and do my activities.  Everything else seemed okay.

This is what my screen looks like when starting up.

It has these 2 options and I always go into windows and have never gone into Debian.

- Windows 10
- Debian GNU/Linux - Continue with install process

[image]

I have googled this on how to remove and tried to find a solid answer for what I am seeing.  What I find doesn't match what I see exactly.  I know that when I can remove it I will then need to expand the Windows partition to use the freed space (which is a different thing) but I need to remove this first.

I have seen video on how to get to the disk partition and view partition.  There is always a video that shows Healthy (Primary Partition) which I don't even have but I don't know which partition has Linux.  This is what I have.

[image]

I only know that when I was installing for Linux I did make some notes during the install as follows (which I barely remember).  I don't know if this helps but I will put it here.

At Partition disks part and just went with the default already there with the VWWare: Guided - use entire disk > SCSI3 (0,0,0) (sda) - 21.5 GB VWWare > VMWare Virtual S > All files in one partition (recommended for new users) > Finish partitioning and write changes to disk. Yes.  Went to Software selection.  I noted that I did not change anything here and just hit Continue.  Got to the screen for Install the GRUB boot loader.  Went with the default of Yes. Then Continue > Install GRUB boot loader I selected /dev/sda > Continue.

Based on what I do see on the dual boot option screen it looks like I didn't actually finish installing it (Debian GNU/Linux - Continue with install process).  I have never gone into it because it has always worked in the windows part.  Maybe this is why I can't see it in disk management like the videos I have found which is a guess on my part.

One additional note:  Videos show to right click delete on the partitions and delete partition.  I wasn't getting that option to delete the partition on the last 3 partitions in the screenshot above.  When I right clicked my only option was Help.  Just the first two with 650 MB and OS (NTFS) in my I am very certain is the Windows partition I am not touching.  I was just checking options but wasn't planning on actually deleting anything till I got assistance.

Sorry that this is long.  I need assistance on how to remove and make sure I remove the right way.

Comment: the top picture appears to be a microsoft windows dual boot screen ... it is not related to linux ... google `windows 10 boot manager`

Comment: Thank you!  It appears I was barking up the wrong tree.  

This looks like it will be a lot simpler than I initially thought.  This forum has been very helpful with another inquiry I had. :). You guys are awesome.